# How can I use a union type of an array of key paths for an object interface to be the union type of those key paths in the interface?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have created a generic type for the type of a path of keys in an object interface: `TypeOfPath<T, P>`.
The paths are arrays of the object interface's keys as well as any nested object key paths, iteratively.

I've also created a few helper types for handling arrays as types.
`Head<T>` defines the first element of an array (can be `undefined`), or `never` if the argument is not an array.
`Tail<T>` defines the rest of the elements of an array (can be empty), or `never` if the argument is not an array.
Standard list-like stuff that I'm a bit surprised is not part of the language.

```
type Head<T> = T extends unknown[] ? T[0] : never;
type Tail<T> = T extends unknown[]
  ? T extends [unknown, ...infer R]
    ? R
    : []
  : never;
type TypeOfPath<T, P> = T extends object
  ? Head<P> extends keyof T
    ? Tail<P> extends []
      ? T[Head<P>]
      : TypeOfPath<T[Head<P>], Tail<P>>
    : never
  : never;
```

All of these types seem to work as expected on first glance.
With `interface I { foo: { bar: boolean }; baz?: number }`:

- the type of `Head<[1, 2, 3]>` and `Head<[1]>` are `1`, `Head<[]>` is `undefined`, `Head<1>` is `never`
- the type of `Tail<[1, 2, 3]>` is `[2, 3]`, `Tail<[1]>` and `Tail<[]>` are `[]`, `Tail<1>` is never
- the type of `TypeOfPath<I, ['foo']>` is `{ bar: boolean }`, `TypeOfPath<I, ['foo', 'bar']>` is `boolean`, `TypeOfPath<I, ['baz']>` is `number | undefined`

However, once I try to use `TypeOfPath<I, ['foo'] | ['foo', 'bar'] | ['baz']>`, the type ends up being `never`.
I would expect the type to be `{ bar: boolean } | boolean | number | undefined`.

It seems that unions to the `P` parameter of `TypeOfPath<T, P>` are always `never`. I thought union generics are distributive. Am I missing something obvious (or, not so obvious) here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `never` because your union includes key arrays of different lengths. Each of your generics receives its argument(s) as a union, so the following situation arises when we evaluate `TypeOfPath<I, ['foo'] | ['foo', 'bar'] | ['baz']>` step by step:

```js
// Set up the arguments to TypeOfPath.
type T = I;
type P = ['foo'] | ['foo', 'bar'] | ['baz'];
// Evaluate the first ternary condition.
type condition1 = T extends object ? true : false; // true
// So take the true branch and evaluate the next condition.
type condition2 = Head<P> extends keyof T ? true : false; // true
// So take the true branch and evaluate the next condition.
type condition3 = Tail<P> extends [] ? true : false; // false
// So take the false branch, calling TypeOfPath recursively.
// Set up the arguments to the new TypeOfPath call.
type Tbis = T[Head<P>]; // number | { bar: boolean } | undefined
type Pbis = Tail<P>; // [] | ['bar']
// Now back to the first ternary condition.
type condition1bis = Tbis extends object ? true : false; // false
// False, because not every branch is an object: two of them have already resolved.
// That leaves us with the false branch, which is never.
```

The simplest workaround would to be to place a union of different-length arrays outside the `TypeOfPath` call; this will work:

```js
TypeOfPath<I, ['foo'] | ['baz']> | TypeOfPath<I, ['foo', 'bar']>
```

If you want to be able to pass a union of different-length arrays to `TypeOfPath` as you intended, I think the solution would involve a combination of the [`Exclude` and `Extract` utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) that separated object and non-object members of the union for separate handling, but the overall complexity of the implementation would be rather greater.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @kdau. I was thinking about the distributive property of generic unions incorrectly, and you are right about `Tbis` failing the `extends object` clause.

However, `Exclude` and `Extract` were not the solution. Instead, I added another condition before the `T extends object` clause: `P extends [Head<P>, ...Tail<P>]`, with the false case as `never`. It could be made a bit less obtuse by inferring the types of `Head<P>` and `Tail<P>` as `L` and `R`, instead.

As far as the concept that I was missing in the original problem, you answered the question.

Comment: As hinted at in this answer and my comment above, returning `never` for the top-most `T extends object` was causing the issue. By limiting first on the `P` parameter to an array, the iterative, distributive union skips over those iterations where it is not an array, and can continue evaluating the other paths. If anyone has a more specific answer as to why `P` must be limited first, please share.